# How to add together the results of two subqueries in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is what I have, it works but I also want the sum of totalServicesSupp + totalTypeExamen, I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    rendezvous.nordv,
    rendezvous.nopatient,
    rendezvous.noservicessupp,
    servicessupplementaires.prix,
    COUNT(rendezvous.noservicessupp) * servicessupplementaires.prix AS totalservicessupp,
    rendezvous.notypeexamen,
    typeexamen.prix,
    COUNT(rendezvous.notypeexamen) AS notypeexamen,
    COUNT(rendezvous.notypeexamen) * typeexamen.prix AS totaltypeexamen
FROM
    rendezvous
    FULL JOIN servicessupplementaires ON rendezvous.noservicessupp = servicessupplementaires.noservicessupp
    FULL JOIN typeexamen ON rendezvous.notypeexamen = typeexamen.notypeexamen
WHERE
        rendezvous.noservicessupp >= 1
    OR
        rendezvous.notypeexamen >= 1
GROUP BY
    nopatient,
    rendezvous.nopatient,
    nordv,
    servicessupplementaires.prix,
    rendezvous.noservicessupp,
    rendezvous.nordv,
    servicessupplementaires.prix,
    typeexamen.prix,
    rendezvous.notypeexamen;
```

How do I get the total of totalServicesSupp + totalTypeExamen also??

Thanks everyone.

****EDIT ///////////////////////////////////////// Still looking for some help, THANKS****

Thanks, this code worked great, now I would like to calculate that Grand Total with a percentage represented by (0.1 for 10% or 0.2 for 20%...)(patient.CouvertureAss is where this is stored) so it's in another table.

I'm having a little trouble implementing that, here's what I tried :

```
SELECT rendezvous.nordv,
       rendezvous.nopatient,
       rendezvous.noservicessupp,
       servicessupplementaires.prix,
       COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix AS totalservicessupp,
       rendezvous.notypeexamen,
       typeexamen.prix,
       COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix AS totaltypeexamen,
       COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix +
           COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix AS grandTotal,
       COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix +
           COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix * (1 - patient.CouvertureAss ) AS TotalPatient
FROM rendezvous
FULL JOIN servicessupplementaires ON rendezvous.noservicessupp = servicessupplementaires.noservicessupp
FULL JOIN typeexamen ON rendezvous.notypeexamen = typeexamen.notypeexamen
FULL JOIN patient ON rendezvous.nopatient = patient.nopatient
WHERE rendezvous.noservicessupp >= 1
   OR rendezvous.notypeexamen >= 1
   OR rendezvous.nopatient >= 1
GROUP BY nopatient,
         rendezvous.nopatient,
         nordv,
         servicessupplementaires.prix,
         rendezvous.noservicessupp,
         rendezvous.nordv,
         servicessupplementaires.prix,
         typeexamen.prix,
         rendezvous.notypeexamen,
         patient.nopatient;
```

Comment: In the above code's `GROUP BY` you have references to `nopatient`, `rendezvous.nopatient`, `nordv` and `rendezvous.nordv` is there a difference between each pair?  Have you test run the above code?

Comment: Please modify your Question to indicate how `patient` relates to the tables already in use by the statements developed thusfar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try...

```
SELECT rendezvous.nordv,
       rendezvous.nopatient,
       rendezvous.noservicessupp,
       servicessupplementaires.prix,
       COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix AS totalservicessupp,
       rendezvous.notypeexamen,
       typeexamen.prix,
       COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ),
       COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix AS totaltypeexamen,
       COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix +
           COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix AS grandTotal
FROM rendezvous
FULL JOIN servicessupplementaires ON rendezvous.noservicessupp = servicessupplementaires.noservicessupp
FULL JOIN typeexamen ON rendezvous.notypeexamen = typeexamen.notypeexamen
WHERE rendezvous.noservicessupp >= 1
   OR rendezvous.notypeexamen >= 1
GROUP BY nopatient,
         rendezvous.nopatient,
         nordv,
         servicessupplementaires.prix,
         rendezvous.noservicessupp,
         rendezvous.nordv,
         servicessupplementaires.prix,
         typeexamen.prix,
         rendezvous.notypeexamen;
```

Please note that at this level you can not say `totalservicessupp + totalTypeExamen AS grandTotal, but any query referring to yours would be able to do so.  For example, the following would give you a list consiting of the total...

```
SELECT totalservicessupp + totalTypeExamen AS grandTotal
FROM
{
    SELECT rendezvous.nordv,
           rendezvous.nopatient,
           rendezvous.noservicessupp,
           servicessupplementaires.prix,
           COUNT( rendezvous.noservicessupp ) * servicessupplementaires.prix AS totalservicessupp,
           rendezvous.notypeexamen,
           typeexamen.prix,
           COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ),
           COUNT( rendezvous.notypeexamen ) * typeexamen.prix AS totaltypeexamen
    FROM rendezvous
    FULL JOIN servicessupplementaires ON rendezvous.noservicessupp = servicessupplementaires.noservicessupp
    FULL JOIN typeexamen ON rendezvous.notypeexamen = typeexamen.notypeexamen
    WHERE rendezvous.noservicessupp >= 1
       OR rendezvous.notypeexamen >= 1
    GROUP BY nopatient,
             rendezvous.nopatient,
             nordv,
             servicessupplementaires.prix,
             rendezvous.noservicessupp,
             rendezvous.nordv,
             servicessupplementaires.prix,
             typeexamen.prix,
             rendezvous.notypeexamen
} tempTable;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Pressing enter or adding in a new line character finishes a Comment.

Comment: Also, how do you calculate the percentage?  i.e. How do you identify which numbers should be totalled together?  And do we divide that by how many of those numbers there are or by the sum of some other corresponding field?  Please update your Question with the answer.

Comment: I updated the question with the answer to my first question but I still need help with calculating the total multiplied by a decimal number which represents a percentage and is stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Put the query in your question into a derived table (subquery with an alias) and add the two numbers.

```
select temp.*
, totalServicesSupp + totalTypeExamen yourSum
from (
sql from your question) temp
```